# Using Postgres and sqlx, filter the data and use it in subsequent queries within a transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlx

I have a simple but quite verbose query that I have to execute. On table A I need to fetch some rows by applying a filter, and then use the filtered result in the follow up queries that calculate various things about the resulting rows. Now I am not sure how to proceed, using a With statement work, but I have no idea how can I now load these results. It would be easier to load the results if I could use a transaction where the other queries would have access to the select result of the first one.

These are all read queries, nothing is being written. The `filtered` is there to filter all of the data and then use it for the next queries. The `stats` is an object representing the data from all of the filtered rows, the paginated requests are just the requests from the `filtered` that we paginate, and the `per_field_stats` are similar to `stats` but they are an array `grouped by` a specific field

This is the general idea of it

```sql
 t, err := template.New("Get").Parse(`
    WITH filtered AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM request
        WHERE true
            {{ if .Period -}}
            AND created_at >= :start_date
            {{ end -}}
    ),
    stats AS (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) as total_count,
        FROM filtered
    ),
    per_field_stats AS (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) as total_count,
        FROM filtered
        GROUP BY field
    ),
    paginated_requests AS (
        SELECT
            id,
...
        FROM filtered
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
        OFFSET :offset
        LIMIT :limit
    )
    `)
```

With the above approach I was unable to load the result into a struct easily, so I decided to try  a transaction with `TEMP TABLES`

```golang
    tx, err := s.db.Beginx()
    if err != nil {}
    defer func() {
        if err == nil {
            return
        }

        if rollbackErr := tx.Rollback(); rollbackErr != nil {
    }()

    dataQuery := struct {
        Period    string    `db:"period"`
}

    // TODO this locks several internal tables during the transaction
    t, err := template.New("GetRequestStats").Parse(`
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_filtered ON COMMIT DROP AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM requests
        WHERE true
            {{ if .Period -}}
            AND created_at >= :start_date
            {{ end -}}
    ...
        )
    `)
    if err != nil {}

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if err := t.Execute(buf, dataQuery); err != nil {}

    sql, args, err := sqlx.Named(buf.String(), dataQuery)
    if err != nil {}

    sql, args, err = sqlx.In(sql, args...)
    if err != nil {}

    sql = s.db.Rebind(sql)

    _, err = s.db.ExecContext(ctx, sql, args...)
    if err != nil {}

    // Query and load stats
    var stats Stats
    row := tx.QueryRowx(`
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) as total_count,
        FROM temp_filtered
    `)
    if err := row.StructScan(&stats); err != nil {}
    result.Stats = stats

    // Query and load per_field_stats
    rows, err := tx.Queryx(`
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) as total_count,
        FROM temp_filtered
        GROUP BY currency
    `)
    if err != nil {}
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {}

    // Query and load paginated_requests
    rows, err = tx.Queryx(`
        SELECT
          *
        FROM temp_filtered
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
        OFFSET $1
        LIMIT $2
    `, dataQuery.Offset, dataQuery.Limit)
    if err != nil {}
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
    }

    if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil
```

But the `TEMP TABLE` is not accessible it seems prior to the commit (where it is also dropped), and it [also locks several tables until the transaction completes (comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3634921/13440079)

A brute force solution would be to apply the filter 3 times, but I am sure there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: *"WITH provides a way to write auxiliary statements for use in a larger query. These statements, which are often referred to as Common Table Expressions or CTEs, can be thought of as defining temporary tables that exist just for one query. Each auxiliary statement in a WITH clause can be a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE; and the WITH clause itself is attached to __a primary statement__ that can also be a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE."* -- Your WITH query is missing a primary statement. Please read the [docs](https://postgresql.org/docs/15/interactive/queries-with.html).

Comment: Also the use of Go's templates seems unnecessary here. The optional created_at filter using `{{ if .Period }}` can easily be written using plain SQL expressions with parameter placeholders. But if you must use templates then at least consider caching them, creating a new one per request is a waste of resources, however small that waste may be...

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva, but neither of those are applicable to my issue. The first version using `WITH` has the issue of me not being able to load the data into a struct (don't know how, as its quite complex), not that WITH is missing primary clause (which it is, but I haven't even gotten to that error yet). While the second version while being highly unoptimized, it's also not working since the `TEMP` table is not accessible during the transaction. 

I removed some more filters that were previously inside the template for clarity, but I'll note down caching and look into it